# Excel 2013 not starting properly

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013

At our office we all work with Office 2013. Today one of our employees was unable to start Excel. It seems that the program does start, but only shows a very limited screen:[image: Screenshot]

I am unable to minimize, maximize, resize, close or even move the window. The only way to shut it down is to stop the EXCEL process with task manager.

I've already tried the following:

- Repairing the installation of Excel
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Excel
- Starting Excel in save mode, (which does work) and then disabling any and all Add-ins
- Installing every possible update for Windows and Office
- Running as Admin (although the user already is local admin on this pc)

When logging on as a different user, it works without problems.
Also, other Office programs, like Outlook or Word have no problems at all.

Is there anything else I can try?

I know how to remove the local profile of the user, should the problem be a corrupt local profile, but I'd prefer to keep this a last resort, since this would cause me to reconfigure a lot of settings.

Note: the OS is Windows 7 Pro x64

**EDIT:** Thank you for the fast responses. Here are the answers to some of your questions:

- The logs that I could find did not provide any useful info
- System Restore points aren't active on the company pc's (I know, but it's company policy)
- The problem occurs when opening Excel from the icon or from a file, as well as any other way that I could think of.
- Starting in safe mode disables many of the options, including "Advanced"
- I've run a system scan, but no errors were found

Any more ideas?

**EDIT 2:** After trying a couple more times Excel started without problems! I don't knwo what exactly did the trick, but it seems to work as smoothly as before. Thanks a lot for everyone's help!

Comment: if you haven't, look at the system event logs and application logs, there may even be an office log as well.  Might provide some clues.

Comment: Have you tried System Restore to a date it worked? Also, is this starting Excel from the main icon or from opening from a file?

Comment: Try opening Excel in Safe Mode and go to `File>Options>Advanced` then choose "*Disable hardware graphics acceleration*" and try again.

Comment: the obligatory `sfc /scannow` (Run As Administrator Command Prompt) is a possible solution as well.

Comment: @Nick I've edited the question to include some answers to your questions

Comment: @CharlieRB I've edited the question to include some answers to your questions

Comment: @Sun I've edited the question to include some answers to your questions

Comment: What version of Excel are you running (32-bit or 64-bit) ? Go to File > Account > About Excel. Also let us know the Office plan, is it Standard or Professional etc. Are you sure its Excel (desktop) and not Excel 2013 viewer?

Comment: Have you tried placing the cursor on the current boundary and dragging it outward, like you can with some types of windows?